# Unable to execute code after Thread.currentThread().join()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am trying to execute System.exit() which should run after execution of all threads which are dynamically generated based on dynamic client calls.
For every client call e.g. 
`localhost:8080/empController/empDetails` 
there is Thread generated by `Thread.getcurrentThread().`

In order to execute all threads before System.exit(), i have implemented below code

```
try{ 
    Thread.currentThread().join();
    System.exit(0); 
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

But after execution of all threads , program doesn't execute next line of code. However , I have read if we create thread by implementing runnable and create thread by Thread class Object i.e.

```
ThreadTest t1=new ThreadTest();  
ThreadTest t2=new ThreadTest();  
ThreadTest t3=new ThreadTest();  

t1.start(); 
t2.start();  
t3.start(); 

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
System.exit();
```

then it able to exit System. but as per my reqiurement I couldn create static threads. Please provide any suggestions to solve my issue.

Comment: `Thread.join()` makes the current thread wait until the thread it was called on finishes. I'm surprised it doesn't cause an exception.

Comment: Does Thread.join() referring to current thread.

Comment: No, but `Thread.currentThread().join()` certainly does. You can't make your current thread wait on the current thread.